# Immutable js updating a Map in a List

Tags: immutability, immutable.js

Pushing nested data into a Map inside a List

Can anyone tell me: 
 
How do i push a task to either of these users (List items) ideally by specific user id?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
const initialState = Immutable.List([
  Immutable.Map({
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Abe Bell",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Get haircut",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
  }),
  Immutable.Map({
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Chad Dim",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Get real job",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
  })
])
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why your state is structured this way? In my opinion you can simplify this to only use maps all the way. Although it's completely possible to edit the current structure, it's unnecessarily complex. As a generic rule, prefer map over list for performance/simplicity reasons wherever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the way you're building this structure, the `tasks` array will not be an immutable instance, I think that is not what you want, you can use `Immutable.fromJS` to transform all the nested arrays and maps into a Immutable instance.

The way your data is structured you'll have to navigate through the list of users and perform the update when the id matches.

One way of doing that is using `map`

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS([
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Abe Bell",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Get haircut",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Chad Dim",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Get real job",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
  }
]);

let userId = 2;

let newState = initialState.map(user => {
    if (user.get('id') !== userId) {
    return user;
  }
  return user.update('tasks', tasks => {    
    return tasks.push(Immutable.fromJS({
      id: 3,
      title: "new task",
      status: false
    }))
  });
});
```

Although this will do what you want,I think you should change your data to a map instead of a list if this kind of operation is something recurrent in your application. This will make things easier and faster.

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Abe Bell",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Get haircut",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
   },
   "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Chad Dim",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Get real job",
        "status": false
      }
    ]
  }
});

let userId = "2";

let newState = initialState.updateIn([userId, 'tasks'], tasks => {
  return tasks.push(Immutable.fromJS({
    id: 3,
    title: "new task",
    status: false
  }));
});
```